# can't get nav items to align to the right in Bootstrap 4

Tags: javascript, css, bootstrap-4, styling

I've been attempting to move the nav items (and only the nav items not the navbar-brand) to the right of the web page. I've tried almost everything but no css styling has solved this. I was able to move the entire thing to the right doing the following but like I said I only want to move the nav items :

```
nav {
    background-color: white;
    float: right;
}
```

Any ideas would be great, thanks!!

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg">
  <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Portfolio</a>
  <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
  </button>

  <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav mr-auto">
      <li class="nav-item active">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link" href="#">Blogs</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">Projects</a>
      </li>
      <li class="nav-item">
        <a class="nav-link " href="#">LinkedIn</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change `.mr-auto` to `.ml-auto`? Adding left margin would push the nav items to the right.

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
    <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto">
    ...
```

[image]

**demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/davidliang2008/z9j7a82t/2/